# Connecting to a machine which is behind a university gateway

Tags: ssh, remote

I have a username and password to connect to a remote machine which is behind a university gateway (using ssh). However, I don't have a username and password to connect to the gateway itself.

I tried to so some port forwarding without luck. What else can I do (which is legitimate)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases universities/institutes/companies provide [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) for their students/employees to connect to the machines from outside. As long as a VPN tunnel is open, you then can connect to the remote machine via SSH as if it is in your home network.

You should ask the IT department for details.

Comment: The issue is that I'm not a student of that university and, I need to run some calculations on the remote machine due to collaboration I'm participating in. The IT department of the university is not willing to go through the bureaucracy of giving me a username and password for the entire network

Comment: @Yotam: Then there is probably no 'direct' way. As you said, you've got a collaboration going on, it might be possible to use the account of your collaborator. NOT to connect (!), but to launch your calculations. Set up a shared directory somewhere outside (e.g. private web server and password protected) and use a simple Shell script on your collaborator's machine to regularly pull new tasks from the shared directory and execute them. Finally it should put all results back into the shared directory. That's how I would do it.

Comment: OK. thanks. I'll figure something of that sort out.

Answer (score 2):

a reverse ssh tunnel should do what you want.

more info here: http://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling